# Try Catch ArgumentNullException in loop, log and continue

Tags: c#, error-handling

I have a simple method that takes person information from a WebService and uses StringBuilder to build a formatted string.

```
public List<string> Process(data)
{
  List<string> returnVal = new List<string>();
  foreach (var entry in AggregrateRecords(data))
  {
     try
     {
       var personEntry = FormatRepository.FormatForSB(entry);
       personResult.Append(posgresEntry);
       personResult.Append(";");
       personResult.Append(Environment.NewLine);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        _logger.Error("String for entry failed.", ex);
     }
  }
      returnVal.Add(personResult.ToString());
}

public static string FormatForSB(PersonEntry entry)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        Func<string, int, string> truncateFunc =
                (val, length) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) && val.Length > length ? val.Substring(0, length) : val;
        sb.AppendFormat("{0,-13}", truncateFunc(entry.City, 13));
        sb.AppendFormat("{0,-2}", truncateFunc(entry.State, 2));
        sb.AppendFormat("{0,-5}", truncateFunc(entry.Zip, 5));
        sb.AppendFormat("{0,-1}", truncateFunc(Regex.Replace(entry.HomePhone, @"[^\d]", ""), 10));
     } catch  (ArgumentNullException ex) {
        ex.Data.Add("Entry", entry.ID);
        throw ex;        
    }
    return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

It may happen that entry would return null for Zip or Gender. This indicates a problem with the underlying data, but shouldn't be a show stopper. I would want to pass the record ID of the entry that failed, but I want to continue on. This isn't doing that. The NullException is being caught, but the return sb.ToString() is still causing a failure. What do I need here? I've looked at 'finally' and 'continue', but end up with unreachable code. 
How can I abandon the string that isn't building, log the failure in the calling method and move on to the next entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect to get nulls then this is not an exceptional condition. For the fields where you can get nulls you need to check for null and replace it with an empty string or some other data.

For example, your truncateFunc could easily handle tthe null situation, either implicitly, or based on an argument passed to it.

Also, instead of rethrowing the exception you should just be adding to an errors collection which can be examined after the loop completes. This is also not an exceptional condition but rather a standard method for collecting data issues into an array of some sort. You can throw an ex eption when you're done in the loop, if you'd like to do it that way but that's still exception abuse, IMHO.

Comment: Valid points. I'm embarrassed to admit I failed to add to the example that part that is causing the exception... the Regex (see my code edit). Is it still best to check for null where Regex is used, thus avoiding the exception? Then use your error collection suggestion on those nulls?

Comment: Even with the Regex the same suggestions hold... test for nulls, be it near the Regex, in the loop or a separate method, just get away from throwing the exceptions.